# Backwards rollapply with zoo object

Tags: r, zoo

Suppose I have a zoo object:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4), col2=c("a","b","c","d"))
> v <- zoo(df, order.by = df$col2)
> v
col1 col2
a 1    a   
b 2    b   
c 3    c   
d 4    d
```

I can calculate the mean as:

```
> rollapply(v, 2, by.column = F, function(x) { mean(as.numeric(x[,"col1"])) })
 a   b   c 
1.5 2.5 3.5
```

How do I rollapply `mean` in **DESCENDING** order? (please no solutions where you just reverse the results AFTER applying the regular rollapply)

I would like my output to look like:

```
 d   c   b 
3.5 2.5 1.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oo in zoo stands for *ordered observations* and such objects are always ordered by the index; however, what is shown in the question is not ordered by the index so it cannot be a valid zoo object.

Also, the line starting `v <-` in the question is not likely what is wanted since it seems to ask for a mix of numeric and character data.  Fixing that line and creating a data frame with the order shown we have:

```
library(zoo)

v <- read.zoo(df, index = "col2", FUN = c)
r <- rollapplyr(v, 2, mean)
fortify.zoo(r)[length(r):1, ]
```

giving:

```
  Index   r
3     d 3.5
2     c 2.5
1     b 1.5
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the proper way to create zoo objects. I have been doing it wrong. Will use the `read.zoo` method from now on. So `rollapply` goes from beginning to end and `rollapplyr` goes from end to beginning (i.e. reverse)?

Comment: `v <- zoo(df$col1, df$col2)` would also work.  The first argument must be the data only, not the data and index. The r at the end of rollapplyr specifies the alignment as "right" (as opposed to "center" which is the default if there is no r on the end).  Neither work backwards.  See ?rollapply

Comment: I don't really understand what `align` means. I've read the documentation but not sure what it is telling me.

Comment: If y <- rollapply(x, 3, mean, fill = NA) then y[i] = mean(c(x[i-2], x[i-1], x[i])) if align is "right" and y[i] = mean(c(x[i-1], x[i], x[i+1])) if align is "center" and y[i] = mean(c(x[i], x[i+1], x[i+2])) if align = "left".

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Is there a `rev` method for zoo-objects that would let `rollapply` act on an inverted copy of  the OP's data?

Comment: There is a `rev.zoo` method.

Answer (score 0):

Per G. Grothendieck:

```
rollapply(rev.zoo(v), 2, by.column = F, function(x) { mean(as.numeric(x[,"col1"])) })
```